# Rechargable battery problem in thermocouple simulator

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, simulation

I use a [MicroCal 1 TC](https://thermometer.co.uk/temperature-and-thermometer-calibration-equipment/611-microcal-1-plus-simulator-thermometer.html) thermocouple simulator in my project. The specifications for this simulator say to use 4 x "AA" alkaline 1.5 V batteries, but I used rechargable batteries.

I find that the output voltage of the thermocouple simulator goes up and down. I don't understand why this happens. For example, with the output voltage set to 20 mV, the simulator output is 20 mV, 20 mV, 20 mV, 40 mV (instantly and for a moment), 20 mV, 20 mV.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Perhaps 4x1.2V is not sufficient.

Comment: Have you tried it with alkaline cells to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: We need to know a lot about your simulator to answer this.

Comment: @Drew The simulator is MICROCAL 1 TC simulator. https://thermometer.co.uk/temperature-and-thermometer-calibration-equipment/611-microcal-1-plus-simulator-thermometer.html

Answer (score 2):

The simulator [officially](https://assets.omega.com/manuals/test-and-measurement-equipment/calibration-equipment/temperature-calibration/temperature-tester-and-calibrators/M4961.pdf) can be powered by optional NiMH batteries so it seems unlikely that the batteries are the issue unless they are faulty or intermittent in some way.

Perhaps the unit is faulty or you are using it in some non-intended way (such as into a large capacitive load, which could cause oscillation in a poorly designed unit). It does not appear to be made by one of the well-known instrumentation majors.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong data. TC simulator is MICROCAL 1 TC simulator. Not OMEGA CL540ZA. Sorry for that. Can you analyze again? https://thermometer.co.uk/temperature-and-thermometer-calibration-equipment/611-microcal-1-plus-simulator-thermometer.html

Comment: Pretty much the same comments apply, minus the official NiMH batteries, but they appear to have two levels of low battery detection so the same conclusions should follow if you are not seeing the low battery indicators.